# how to run ansibe playbooks in parallel

Tags: ansible

site.yml

```
---
- import_playbook: common.yml
- import_playbook: redis.yml
- import_playbook: riak.yml
- import_playbook: webserver.yml
- import_playbook: haproxy.yml
```

I want to run these playbooks in parallel.
like

```
- import_playbook: common.yml
# after common.yml run these 4 in parallel
parallel {
- import_playbook: redis.yml
- import_playbook: riak.yml
- import_playbook: webserver.yml
- import_playbook: haproxy.yml
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i am not aware of an easy way, and it probably will not work on debian/ubuntu because apt will fail if you run multiple `apt-get install` commands at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to run the other playbooks in the background

```
> cat project.bash
#!/bin/bash
ansible-playbook common.yml
# Run the other playbooks in the background
ansible-playbook redis.yml > ansible-redis.log &
ansible-playbook riak.yml > ansible-riak.log &
ansible-playbook webserver.yml > ansible-webster.log &
ansible-playbook haproxy.yml > ansible-haproxy.log &
```

To monitor the project open four other terminals and watch the log with "*tail -f ansible- ...*"

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [ansible-parallel](https://pypi.org/p/ansible-parallel), so you can try:

```
pip install ansible-parallel
ansible-parallel *.yml
```

It displays a live update of the progression, and a report at the end.